# Using jQuery jTable with Wordpress Plugin in Admin Menu Area

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, wordpress, jquery-jtable

Wanting to get (and add/edit) records from the DB using jQuery-jTable plugin ([jtable.org](http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted?ref=homebuttons)).  I've enqueued the scripts needed and verified that they are loading via the page source but I don't get anything. According to the getting started guide I should at least get a blank table but I get a blank page. My code is below -- any ideas?

Code to enqueue scripts:

```
function lfc_load_scripts() {
//set global variables
global $plugin_url;

//set variable to use to point to process.php path
$js_vars = array('plugin_url'=>$plugin_url,);

//Load scripts and css for Tabs UI
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
wp_enqueue_script('lfc-ui-js', $plugin_url . 'includes/js/tabs-ui.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script( 'lfc-ui-js', 'js_vars', $js_vars) ;
wp_register_style( 'lfc_jquery_admin_css', $plugin_url . 'includes/css/ui.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lfc_jquery_admin_css' );

//Load scripts and css for jTable
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('lfc-jtable-js', $plugin_url . 'includes/js/jtable/jquery.jtable.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_style( 'lfc_jtable_css', $plugin_url . 'includes/js/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lfc_jtable_css' );

    //Load main jQuery file
wp_enqueue_script('lfc-process-js', $plugin_url . 'includes/js/process.js', array('jquery'));

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'lfc_load_scripts');
```

And this is the jQuery (as per the instructions on the jTable.org page)

```
$('#FighterTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Table of people',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
            createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
            updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
            deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
        },            
        fields: {
            PersonId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Author Name',
                width: '40%'
            },
            Age: {
                title: 'Age',
                width: '20%'
            },
            RecordDate: {
                title: 'Record date',
                width: '30%',
                type: 'date',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested jTable in a dummy plugin and it worked showing a blank table with the declared fields (`Name`, `Age` and `RecordDate`).

Issues with your code:

**1)** The following:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lfc-ui-js', $plugin_url . 'includes/js/tabs-ui.js', array('jquery'));
```

Can be declared as:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'lfc-ui-js', 
    $plugin_url . 'includes/js/tabs-ui.js', 
    array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-tabs' ) 
);
```

And the same for the script `'lfc-jtable-js'`. Maybe, the one with your code need to be enqueued on [footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

**2)** Wrap your code with `(document).ready`, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $('#FighterTableContainer').jtable({
        // rest of the code
    });
});
```